# javascript image rotation on a canvas

Tags: javascript

Im drawing images on a canvas for resize purposes.  I have a problem with when I rotate an image 90 degrees it scales weirdly.  I have prepared a jFiddle to show what I'm talking about.
 Thanks for any help.  http://jsfiddle.net/6ZsCz/554/

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var angleInDegrees=0;

var image=document.createElement("img");
image.onload=function(){
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}
image.src="https://www.kick-flip.com/img/full/7331fa5cca3be47ce28749cba90f38f7.jpg";

$("#clockwise").click(function(){ 
angleInDegrees+=90;
drawRotated(angleInDegrees);
});

$("#counterclockwise").click(function(){ 
angleInDegrees-=90;
drawRotated(angleInDegrees);
});
ctx.save();
var MaxWidth = 150;
var MaxHeight = 200;
function drawRotated(degrees){
ctx.clearRect(0,0,MaxWidth,MaxHeight);


var temp = MaxWidth;
MaxWidth = MaxHeight;
MaxHeight = temp;

var can = $("#canvas");
can.attr("width",MaxWidth).attr("height",MaxHeight);    
ctx.translate(MaxWidth/2,MaxHeight/2);
ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);

ctx.drawImage(image,-MaxWidth/2,-MaxHeight/2,MaxWidth,MaxHeight);
ctx.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem.  It's a weird scaling issue.  I have attached to working version.

http://jsfiddle.net/6ZsCz/623/

Updated the draw statements to such:

```
if(degrees<0) var remainder = 360-(Math.abs(degrees)%360);   
else var remainder = degrees%360;
switch(remainder) {
    case 90:
    case 270:
        ctx.drawImage(image,-MaxHeight/2,-MaxWidth/2,MaxHeight,MaxWidth);
        break;
    case 0:
    case 180:
        ctx.drawImage(image,-MaxWidth/2,-MaxHeight/2,MaxWidth,MaxHeight);
        break;          
}
```